# Modify align text in bootstrap 4 table-thead

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to modify the style in my table. In this case in thead, so the text will use just one row. For this, I would like to use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

```css
.table-font-size {
    font-size: 13px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-sm table-responsive table-bordered table-font-size">
  <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
      <th class="thead-nowrap" th:text="#{large.text1}">Large text 1</th>
      <th class="thead-nowrap" th:text="#{large.text2}">Large text 2</th>
      <th class="thead-nowrap" th:text="#{large.text3}">Large text 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

works for all table, but I don't want that.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You have missed a parenthesis after class name `.table-thead-nowrap` in your style, I think that might be a problem

Comment: Right, was a typo!!!, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 .table .thead-nowrap{
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: works, just added parenthesis to your suggestion. thanks